После обновления в PyCharm не подсвечиваются ошибки
Раньше я пользовался Pycharm и когда отступ был не правильный или функция не была выделена с двух сторон 2 строками, то это все подсвечивалось желтым цветом, а сейчас ничего нету. Как исправить?


Не знаю насчет желтого, но проблема форматирования это  Settings - Editor - Inspections - General - Incorrect Formating включить. И да, вроде раньше она была включена по дефолту.

Мне помог комментарий vitidev
"Не знаю насчет желтого, но проблема форматирования это Settings - Editor - Inspections - General - Incorrect Formating включить. И да, вроде раньше она была включена по дефолту."

Проверить в настройках :
Settings - Editor - Inspections - PEP8 coding style violations (Это должно быть включено)
Отсутствие ожидаемых двух пустых строк - это E302, не должно быть в Ignored errors

